# Manage Windows System Image Backups on a disk

Tags: windows, backup, images

I have an external hard disk, and i use a partition on this disk for Windows 10 System Image Backups. In theory, if disaster strikes, i have a complete image of my SSD which i can restore my system from.

How can i manage the backups stored on this disk? If i go to create another image, Windows detects the image(s) that are already there, and tells me the date the most recent one was created (see below), so it obviously knows all about the images that are present.

[image: Create System Image dialog in Windows 10]

What do i do if i want to delete one of potentially many images in the "WindowsImageBackup" folder, apart from try and do it manually without damaging any other images? Something a bit like [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/storage-at-microsoft/managing-backup-disk-space/ba-p/424098), however i can't seem to find this in Windows 10.

Comment: You are over estimating the usefulness of those Windows System Images, in my experience, they are not complete enough to recovery a system after a complete disk failure.

Comment: OK. In that case, what is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete older *complete* images; they're just files, like any other; *but use the tools [management dialog](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/deleting-previous-system-images-backups-windows) to delete them*, to keep the catalog correct. Unlike [Restore Points](https://www.techtarget.com/searchwindowsserver/definition/restore-point), which are a delta (difference) recording only the state of changed items, a full drive image is a self-contained snapshot of an *entire* drive.  Identify the image **by date**, since [the image is named by GUID (Globally Unique Identifier)](https://pureinfotech.com/create-windows-10-system-image-backup/), rather than date-time (which can be confusing, e.g., when the locale reverts from Daylight Savings Time to Standard Time, with an hour repeated.

If the external HDD has sufficient room, you can create additional images.

Note that *Windows 10 System Image Backup* [is no longer maintained](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-make-full-backup-windows-10), though still usable. You might look at third-party tools, such as free [Macrium Reflect](https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/macrium_reflect_free_edition.html) or [DriveImage XML](https://www.runtime.org/driveimage-xml.htm) or [alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/driveimage-xml/). Most of these tools also simplify creating bootable rescue media to restore the image when Windows cannot be booted.

Personally, I've found third-party tools *more reliable* for restoring a drive than Windows System Backup, and *far* more reliable than *Restore Points*. **Verify any image after completion**; look at files inside it and check for completeness, at least until you're comfortable with the software's reliability. Don't trust a tool blindly. At a firm for which I worked, they made daily backups, only to find *none* of them actually worked when data was damaged!

Comment: So if a am manually deleting an image, what do i do with the the other folders inside "WindowsImageBackup\ComputerName", such as "Catalog", "SPPMetadataCache", etc? Anything?

Comment: See https://www.thewindowsclub.com/deleting-previous-system-images-backups-windows for using *System Image Backup* to manage the files, rather than delete them manually. And, as Ramhound states, third-party tools might be a more reliable alternative.